# Xamarin.SideBar on different pages with navigation controller

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, sidebar

So i'm using [**this(Xamarin.SideBar)**](https://components.xamarin.com/view/SidebarNavigation) component in my project.
The biggest problem that i need to have **SideMenu** on all my main pages(that are represented as tabs,each one have an navigation controller,see pics).

So my pages looks like on the screen:
[image]
where ***A,B,C,D,E,G*** are tabbed pages,which contains a navigation controller.(green circle means that were located now at page ***A***)

And now i'm opening my ***SideBar***
[image]
Menu are opened and the first button clicked,bam and we're on another ***ViewController*** that holds ***Navigation stack*** with button ***Back*** to ***ViewController***(page) that called ***A***(same for other pages from tab).

---

My storyboards looks like:

[image]

And i'm so confused how to achieve my goal !?

Seems that i need to make an ***BaseController*** that will create ***ONEs*** this ***MenuController*** of ***SideBar***  , but architecture of Xamarin.SideBar component scares me,because i need to put everytime a ***NavController*** and ***ContentArea***...

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not use the Xamarin Component, instead use the nuget package that is more updated. [Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SidebarNavigation/) the link. Don't worry it's the same library, it seems they will not update the Component, but who needs a Component when you have a nuget!

Regarding your question, yeah you are correct, you will need to create a BaseViewController that will be holding the side menu.  Your main controllers (A,B,C,D,E,F,G) will all be deriving from this it so you don't have to be repeating code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already changed package(ill explain later). So the problem remains with Navigation Stack. What should i do to store it properly? I'm stuck at this moment. What is correct why to do this with TabBar controller and navigation controllers?(see my attached screen of storyboard in question).

Comment: okay,can you watch,i have made gifs animation : 1) its works like's this https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG5tB.gif (navigation stack remains) 2) it wont work with TabBarController : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgYVk.gif . But why? Any idea?

Comment: yeah, can see.. how are you navigating when selecting an option from the menu when using tabs?

Comment: at first step,i find VC via storyboards,then i'm doing like this: ShowViewController(MyVC_ThatWasCreatedViaStoryBoard,this);

Comment: Get an object of your TabBarController in the storyboard and just select the index of the view you wanna display with the `SelectedIndex` property

Comment: any example? I dont understand second part of your approach.

Comment: @VetaLio can get you something tonight (EST)

Comment: or can you explain why navigation controller lost after using tab bar controller!?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136382/discussion-between-apineda-and-vetalio).